# Does COALESCE work properly with VIEWs?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have my `view` definition:

```
CREATE VIEW `view` AS
  SELECT a.id,
    COALESCE(COALESCE(b.name, c.name), a.name) AS name
  FROM a_table a
  LEFT JOIN b_table b on a.b_id = b.id
  LEFT JOIN c_table c on a.c_id = c.id
```

And after I'm updating `a_table` row with new `name` it doesn't get updated in my `view`. But if I change `name` to `COALESCE(a.name, COALESCE(b.name, c.name)) AS name` it works.

As I understand the reason is in `COALESCE`. It takes the first `not null` value and in my case it's `b.name` and gets updated only when `b.name` is updated.

Is there any option to updated the `view` when any of `COALESCE` values are changed?

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  The backticks suggest you are using MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COALESCE()` works fine in views.  It also takes multiple arguments, so I would suggest writing this as:

```
CREATE VIEW `view` AS
  SELECT a.id, COALESCE(b.name, c.name, a.name) AS name
  FROM a_table a LEFT JOIN
       b_table b 
       ON a.b_id = b.id LEFT JOIN
       c_table c 
       ON a.c_id = c.id;
```

Views are not "updated".  They are SQL code that is plugged into queries when the view is reference.  The data comes from the underlying tables.